# Batch file to execute a java application

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, java-7, java-6

I have a java application I would like my Windows batch file to execute. May I know why the following batch file codes do not work and how I can correct them ? The script should check for 32bit Java first before proceeding to check for 64 bit Java.

I would also like my batch file to handle Java 6 and above versions and inclusive of JRE or JDK environments. How would I modify my batch file to handle them.

Batch Script:

```
@ECHO OFF 
IF EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java" (
    start C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\java -jar %~dp0\JavaShop.jar
) ELSE (
    IF EXIST "C:\Program Files\Java" C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\java -jar %~dp0\JavaShop.jar
    ELSE ECHO Java software not found on your system. Please go to http://java.com/en/ to download a copy of Java.
    PAUSE
)
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why 32bit first? 32bit is basically dead

Comment: didnt understand your question properly, do u want to execute a batch file from your java program? or You are trying to run your JavaShop.jar from your batch file?

Comment: What's the error here? Maybe names with spaces are a problem. Try to "double quote" them.

Comment: Please tell us what does not work and how you know it does not work.

Comment: when you execute this script what happens? does "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\java -jar %~dp0\JavaShop.jar" work from the prompt (outside any script)?

Comment: What if my Java is not in `C:\Program Files` or `C:\Program Files (x86)`? Don't assume that everybody has their Java installed in the default location.

Comment: The above script I posted does not work because no Java processes were started and nothing happened.

Comment: @rao_555, I am trying to run the batch script to start my jar file.

Comment: where is the Batch file located in your system? is it in the same directory as the javashop.jar?

Comment: Yes it is next to the main java file.

Answer (score 6):

I think you're onto a loser if you try to anticipate all likely install paths.  Surely if Java's available on the machine, it's already on its path, i.e. available via just:

```
java
```

Also in your "start" line, and assuming a hardcoded path was good enough, you would need " chars around the path, due to the space character in it.

Comment: +1; e.g. I do never install my JDKs, JREs in default location.

Comment: I installed Java JDK as 64 bit and when I go to my command line and type java, it tells me it is not recognized. I need to specifically go to the 64 bit Java to execute it otherwise it wouldn't be recognized.

Comment: if you can't go to C:\ and run "java", then it's not on your machine's path. For more info here, read: 

http://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml

Answer (score 1):

You have space characters in your execution path. Try this

```
@ECHO OFF 
IF EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7" (
    start "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe" -jar %~dp0\JavaShop.jar
) ELSE (
    IF EXIST "C:\Program Files\Java\jre6" 
    start "C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\java.exe" -jar %~dp0\JavaShop.jar
    ELSE ECHO Java software not found on your system. Please go to http://java.com/en/ to download a copy of Java.
    PAUSE
)
```

The best thing to do though is to check if the environmental variable JAVA_HOME is set. If it is set, then java is installed in the system.

```
@ECHO OFF 
IF EXIST %JAVA_HOME% (
    start %JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe -jar %~dp0\JavaShop.jar
) ELSE (
    ECHO Java software not found on your system. Please go to http://java.com/en/ to download a copy of Java.
    PAUSE
)
```

If you don't have a JAVA_HOME set you could just try the `java` command itself.

```
@ECHO OFF 
IF EXIST java (
    start java -jar %~dp0\JavaShop.jar
) ELSE (
    ECHO Java software not found on your system. Please go to http://java.com/en/ to download a copy of Java.
    PAUSE
)
```

Comment: I ran it and it says the syntax is incorrect without specifying.

Comment: @thotheolh which version? the JAVA_HOME one?

Comment: I noticed that my JAVA_HOME is not set despite Java 7 already installed in the system. Both versions had syntax incorrect errors.